# To prove an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Can anyone give me some hint on the following problem? Many thanks!

For $a>b>1$, show that 
$a^{b^a}>b^{a^b}$.

Comment: What happens if you take logarithms on both sides of the inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^{b^a}>b^{a^b} \iff b^a\ln a>a^b\ln b \iff \dfrac{\ln a}{\ln b}> \dfrac{a^b}{b^a}$

There are two cases:

1. $a^b<b^a \implies \dfrac{a^b}{b^a} <1 ,$ but $\dfrac{\ln a}{\ln b}>1$, so it is OK.
2. $a^b>b^a \implies \dfrac{\ln a}{\ln b}>\dfrac{a}{b}$, it remains to prove:

$\dfrac{a}{b}> \dfrac{a^b}{b^a} \iff b^{a-1}>a^{b-1} \iff \dfrac{a-1}{\ln a}>\dfrac{b-1}{\ln b}$

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{\ln x}, f'(x)=\dfrac{\ln x+\dfrac{1}{x}-1}{(\ln x)^2} $

Also let $g(x)=\ln x+\dfrac{1}{x}-1,g'(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x^2}>0 $ where $x>1 \implies f'(x)>0 \implies f(x) $ is mono increasing function when $x>1$, so

$\dfrac{a-1}{\ln a}>\dfrac{b-1}{\ln b}$ is true.

QED.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Take logarithms twice; then your claim is equivalent to showing that
$$a \ln{b} + \ln \ln{a} > b \ln{a} + \ln \ln b$$

whenever $a > b$.

Comment: Here the log-log terms are in the right order, but the a ln b and b ln a are reversed, so it's not immediate from this re-write.

Comment: In the last comment I should only have said "the a ln b and b ln a *might be* reversed (depending on a,b)".